# How to send files in a formdata from their base64 string in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm currently working on a Node.js middleware and I need to send a file to an API using a formdata.

I've managed to do this when I use a file on my local storage using fs to create a ReadStream and put it in my formdata.

I use request-promise to send my data:

```
var formData = {
  'file': fs.createReadStream('myfile.jpg')
}

var options = {
  method: method,
  uri: url,
  formData: formData
}

return rp(options).then(response => response)
```

Now I don't fully understand what is going on under the hood.

I need to send a file which I only have in a base64 string, and the API is waiting for a file just like I sent "myfile.jpg".

I've tried to send a buffer built from the base64 string:

```
var buffer = Buffer.from(base64string, 'base64')

var formData = {
  'file': buffer
}
```

But it didn't work. 
I could eventually create a binary file from my Buffer and use fs to create a stream from it but I hope there is a better way to achieve this.

Also I'm not confortable working with things I don't understand so if you have any informations on how file streams work with formdatas, I'll take it!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using Axios and FormData

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');

// Create a new form instance
const form = new FormData();

const file =  fs.readFileSync('./example.jpg');
// or/and
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./example.jpg');

// For base64

const buffer = Buffer.from(YOUR_BASE64_STRING, 'base64');

// Create a form and append image with additional fields

form.append('file', file, 'example.jpg');
// or/and
form.append('fileStream', fileStream, 'example.jpg');
// or/and
form.append('buffer', buffer, 'example.jpg');

// Send form data with axios
const response = await axios.post('https://example.com', form, {
    headers: {
        ...form.getHeaders(),
        // some other headers if needed
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work in your setting, but what I have done is create a buffer from the data and then append a "path" property. This property allows request or some other library to guess the type of the data:

```
  var istream = new Buffer(image, 'base64');
  istream.path = "pic.png";
  server.post( "/upload", {"file":istream}, function(...){} )
```

The upload worked flawlessly. This depends on your http layer (I guess).

Answer (score 0):

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(fileBase64Encoded, 'base64');
const form = new FormData();
form.append('image', buffer, fileName);
const headers = {headers: {'Content-Type':`multipart/form-data; boundary=${form.getBoundary()}`}};
return server.post(`${process.env.SERVER}/upload`, form, headers);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.